# Dropping individual grains of sand at a constant rate

Tags: mechanical-engineering, machine-design, machine-elements

I want to build an optical sorting machine that uses air pressure to sort out sand (small amounts, a few grams, varying about 250-750μm in size) of a given color. This requires sand to pass past a camera and a valve at a somewhat constant rate, leaving space between individual particles so differing colors aren't blocking each other during inspection or sorted out together.

How can I ensure this happens between the funnel input and the narrow chute where this happens?

Comment: With a 3:1 diameter variation you'll have a 27:1 weight variation. I think you're going to struggle with this one. How many grains per second?

Comment: About 100-500 would be nice, the fastest acting valves I could find switch at around 1000Hz

Comment: @Transistor Perhaps it would be best to sort them into rough size groups with sieves first, and then sort the different streams sequentially - assuming I only have one valve that may be a more realistic approach

Comment: Using a belt-type instead of chute sorter might be a more realistic approach, it also gives more processing time.